# Regular Noetherian Local Ring is Integral Domain

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian, regular-rings

I am currently reading a proof of the fact that every regular Noetherian local ring $R$ is an integral domain.

The proof argues by induction on $d=\operatorname{dim}R$. The base case $d=0$ is clear. Now let $d>0$ and let $x_1,\ldots,x_d$ be a system of parameters generating the unique maximal ideal $m$ and let $P_1,\ldots,P_r$ denote the minimal prime ideals in $R$. By prime avoidance, choose an element $a\in m\setminus m^2$ which is not contained in any of the minimal prime ideals. Then, since $a,x_2,\ldots,x_d$ form a system of parameters of $R$, the dimension of $R/(a)$ is $d-1$. Furthermore, $x_2,\ldots,x_d$ give rise to a system of parameters of $R/(a)$ generating the maximal of $R/(a)$. Therefore $R/(a)$ is regular and by the induction hypothesis, an integral domain. In particular $(a)$ is prime in $R$ and therefore there exists a minimal prime, say $P_1$, such that $P_1\subseteq (a)$. It follows $P_1=(a)P_1$ and by Nakayma's Lemma $P_1=0$, implying $R$ is an integral domain.

What I don't see is, where did we need, that $a\notin m^2$? What goes wrong if $a$ happens to be in $m^2$?

EDIT: The Element $a$ has the form
$$
a=x_1+\sum_{i=2}^d c_i x_i
$$
for some coefficients $c_i\in R$.

EDIT2: I just read in Rotman's ["Advanced Modern Algebra"](https://dsury.com/content/images/books/113-rotman.pdf) Proposition 11.165, which states that elements $x_1,\ldots, x_d$ form a minimal generating set for $m$ if and only if the cosets $\overline{x_i} = x_i + m^2$ form a basis of $m/m^2$. So apparently not lying in $m^2$ is necessary for being a minimal system of parameters for a regular Noetherian local ring, since otherwise they would be linearly dependent in $m/m^2$.
However, I don't understand why $m(m/B)=(B+m^2)/B$ holds in Rotman's proof. So if we could settle this, I would be happy.

Comment: Does it have something to do with $a, x_2,...$ forming a system of parameters (whatever that is)?  It  feels like you're upgrading $x_1$ to something else for some special purpose.

Comment: hi Squeezelemma; this proof is rather unclear. for instance, you say that $a,x_2,\dots,x_d$ is a system of parameters of $R$, but there is no guarantee of this; what if I have chosen $a=x_2$?

Comment: for a concrete example, take $R=k[[x,y]]$; then $R$ has a unique minimal prime ideal, $(0)$, and has a regular system of parameters given by $x_1=x$ and $x_2=y$. if you take $a=x_2$, then $a$ is not contained in the minimal prime of $R$ or in $m^2$, but the proof still does not go through.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thanks for your comment. You are right. I thought, the only relevant properties we need $a$ to fulfill are being an element of $m\setminus m^2$ and not lying in any of the minimal primes. I added how $a$ is choosen.

Comment: @rschwieb Given a local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $m$ a system of parameters is a set of elements $x_1,...,x_d \in m$ such that $(x_1,...,x_d)$ is $m$-primary and $\operatorname{dim}R=d$. So I think $a,x_2,...,x_d$ being a system of parameters should not be the reason. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I don't understand why $m(m/B)=(B+m^2)/B$ holds in Rotman's proof. So if we could settle this, I would be happy.

That is just the coset module action and coset arithmetic.  By definition, $r(s+B)=rs+B$, and so $m(m/B)$ is some submodule of $m/B$ which contains everything of the form $m_1m_2+B$ for every $m_1, m_2\in m$.

One would like to say this is $m^2/B$ but there is no guarantee $m^2$ contains $B$. Therefore the best we can say is that it is $(m^2+B)/B$